# Pandas python multiple export read text files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, operating-system, glob

Helo anyone can help me to read and export multiple files. I have daily file of customers data. How can I autoread all the files:

```
import pandas
with open("Customers_1oct.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "Detail Indicator": line[0:2].strip(),
            "Name": line[2:102].strip(),
            "Ref No": line[182:232].strip(),
            "Ind": line[232:234].strip(),
            "Amount": line[234:249].strip(),
         
        }
        for line in data.splitlines()
        if len(line) > 1
    ]
)
df
```

I also want to export into multiple file, how can i do it?

```
datatoexcel = pandas.ExcelWriter('1oct.xlsx') 
  

df.to_excel(datatoexcel) 
  

print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```

Comment: In which way do you want to export into multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your current code in a function.
2. Use e.g. `glob` to retrieve the list of files.
3. Call your function for each of the files using a `for` loop.

Example:

```py
from glob import glob

def process(filename):
    print("Processing file %s..." % filename)

for item in glob("*.txt"):
    process(item)
```

```
$ ls
script.py  test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt  test4.txt
$ python3 script.py
Processing file test1.txt...
Processing file test4.txt...
Processing file test2.txt...
Processing file test3.txt...
```